# How to rewrite exact url while passing other paths through

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm new to mod_rewrite, so I know this is probably a simple fix.  I want to rewrite www.abc.com to www.xyz.com ONLY.  I only want to do this in firefox.  I do not want www.abc.com/def to redirect to www.xyz.com.  Currently, I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "firefox" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xyz.com [L,R=302]
```

I understand that the ^(.*)$ portion is what is allowing everything else to be redirected as well.  What should I enter in there that will ONLY redirect www.abc.com?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the rule to

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.xyz.com [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I changed from ^(.*)$ to ^/?$...didn't seem to work.  Now it no longer redirects at all.

Comment: Apparently something is wrong with the setup on my machine.  Tried it on other machine and it works.  Thank you.